# Inject a service into a component

Tags: typescript, angular

FYI: using angular2 (2.0.0-alpha.45) & TypeScript (1.6.2)

Trying to create a simple service to inject into a component.

The error I'm getting:

> Cannot resolve all parameters for {ComponentName}(?). Make sure they all have valid type or annotations.

Bootstrapping:

```
bootstrap(App, [ROUTER_PROVIDERS, HTTP_PROVIDERS]);
```

Service (my-service.ts):

```
import {Injectable} from 'angular2/angular2';
@Injectable()
export class MyService {
  public doSomething() {}
}
```

Consuming Component:

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/angular2';
import {MyService} from './my-service';
export class ListManager{
  constructor(private myService: MyService){
    console.log('myService', myService);
  }
}
```

> Things I've tried

- In the service:

  - marking/un-marking the service with `@Injectable`
- In bootstrapping:

  - Adding/removing `MyService` into the bootstrapping list of providers
- In component

  - specifying the service as a provider `@Component({providers: [MyService]})`
  - specifying the service as a binding `@Component({bindings: [MyService]})`

Comment: Is `ComponentName` your service? What are you passing to its constructor?  Why are you importing `MyService` and then calling `ListService`? What is this line `import {Component} from 'angular2/angular2';'angular2/router';`?

Comment: `ComponentName` is the name of the component I'm trying to inject the service into... `ListService` is a typo when creating the question was making names more generic for here (corrected) (router was holdover when copy/pasting in here... removed as its not relevant)

Comment: I'm also using webpack, and am leaning towards that being the culprit (not webpack itself, but my usage)

Comment: It seems that your problem is not in `MyService`. You are injecting the latter into `ListManager`, so I'm guessing you are injecting `ListManager` into your Component, if that's the case, you should put `@Injectable()` in `ListManager` instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you would do:

```
constructor(private myService: MyService){
    console.log('myService', myService);
}
```

You also have to specify the service as a provider in @Component definition

```
@Component({
  ...
  providers: [MyService]})
```

Comment: Thanks, this is something I've already tried, I'll update my question to make it a little clearer

Comment: This is how I ended up solving the issue, but I had bigger issues in regards to a webpack build process. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this in your component:

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/angular2';
import {Inject} from 'angular2/core';
import {MyService} from './my-service';

export class ListManager{
  private listService: ListService;

  constructor(@Inject(ListService) listService: ListService){
      console.log('listService', listService);
  }
}
```

(Pay attention to the new import and `@Inject` inside the constructor)

Let me know if it worked for you. A plunker will also help isolating the problem.

Answer (score 0):

**inject()** is a function that can be used to dynamically retrieve a dependency or service at runtime. It allows you to inject a service or dependency in a method or property decorator, or in any other place outside of the constructor where you need to access a service or dependency.

prerequisites: Angular >=14

```
import { Component, inject } from '@angular/core';
import { MyService } from './my.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'di-component',
  template: '<h1>{{ data}}</h1>'
})
export class DIComponent implements OnInit {
  data: string;

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    const runtimeService = inject(MyService);
    this.data = myService.getServiceMethod();
  }
}
```